# How long you would be with a junior title?

Tags: job-offer, new-job, canada, new-hires, junior

I got a part-timeast 6 months with the same junior job title. I worked for a total of 2 years and 2 years and 9 months. I have never had raise in my salary.

Comment: It's unlikely anybody here can possibly answer the question: "how long do they usually keep a person as a junior?". Maybe you should be asking your supervisor, they will have a better idea about what is required for you to step up.

Comment: And it looks like you've only been qualified for 6 months. No massive surprise that you may still have the junior title.

Comment: This can be because they don't want to pay senior salary or because you are not yet self reliant enough to be able to work fully on your own.

Comment: How "part time" was your part time? If you worked for two years and 20 hours per week, you have the same experience as someone who worked there for one year, full-time. "Junior" does not change with real time, it changes with experience you gather.

Comment: Are you producing good work? That's the real question. Also, what do you mean by part-time? How many hours are you working? If you haven't received a raise, try finding a new job with a new employer. That's the secret. Don't just look for a job when you're desperate. Look for a job when you already have a job.

Answer (score 5):

It is not beneficial to you to think in terms of general "time of service before advancement". You cannot asses that at all and the mileage will vary significantly for all individuals with their unique circumstances in professional and personal life.

You can however determine your situation by doing two main things.

1. Negotiations with your current employer (you have already started with this - great!).
2. Try to apply elsewhere and get a feeling what offers your skills can attract right now.

Then it is up to you to weigh the advantages and disadvantages of each offer and choose to either stay or move on.

Answer (score 2):

You supervisor can answer that question. I'm no fan of those "junior" and "senior" job titles, they are not often in use where I live. Basically every company can have their own definition what they call "junior" or "senior".

Most of the time it boils down to experience and independence. A junior needs someone to check their work or has to ask questions to sucessfully complete their assignments. A senior does the work alone and can help others doing their work. But your company could have other milestones.

Ask your supervisor for feedback about your work, tell him you would like to know what it takes for you to advance to "senior". But don't put too much weight on the title. Your job needs to be fun for you and pay the bills. If it does, who cares about the title?

Answer (score 2):

I've worked with some developers with more than 10 years experience who I considered still to be "junior".  In my view, "junior" vs. "senior" is all about behavior and results vs. time on the job.

In your organization, keep your eye on those who you consider to be "senior" and get to know them.  Seek out a mentor who can help guide you to develop senior-level skills and thinking.  Discuss your career goals with your manager.  In most companies there are some objective criteria between job categories.  While these are not always hard-and-fast, they can help you start moving in that direction.

When you meet with your manager for reviews, be sure you have done YOUR homework and be prepared with your performance vs. those criteria when seeking a promotion.  In nearly all companies you must show a consistent pattern of performing well at a level beyond your current job classification to be promoted.  It's a fooling choice to promote someone in the hopes that they will "grow" into the position.